# What webserver does Splunk use on Windows?

Tags: windows, web-server, splunk

Is it a propietary web server? I thought it used Apache, but I've been looking through the installation files and can't find any references.

I'm trying to secure the access to the free version of Splunk and solutions I've found so far are for Apache.

Comment: How does that relate to a technical problem you try to solve? Please read the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`splunkd` provides the Splunk web interface, since version 6.2](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Installation/Splunksarchitectureandwhatgetsinstalled).  It appears to be proprietary, and no information about its internal workings is freely available.

---

- New for version 6.2, splunkd also provides the Splunk Web user interface. It allows users to search and navigate data stored by Splunk servers and to manage your Splunk deployment through a Web interface. It communicates with your Web browser via REpresentational State Transfer (REST).
- splunkd runs a Web server on port 8089 with SSL/HTTPS turned on by default.
- It also runs a Web server on port 8000 with SSL/HTTPS turned off by default.

---